# Why are the tag's Top User stats incorrect?

Tags: support, tags

I tried to see how close I was to 200 answers in [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) tag, and realized that, despite answering a bunch of Qs last couple of days, I was still at the same 170 answers as per "[Top Users](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/harry-potter/topusers)" list in Harry Potter tag page as I was a couple of days ago.

This seems off, and is confirmed by the fact that [searching for my total Harry Potter posts brings up 250](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:976%20%5Bharry-potter%5D) as of now; whereas Top Users list has me at 170A+74Q=244 posts.

Why is the Top Users statistics off?

Answer (score 2):

While the Top Users page is cached and won't immediately update, it's not off. You also mentioned the following:

> This seems off, and is confirmed by the fact that [searching for my total Harry Potter posts brings up 250](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:976%20%5Bharry-potter%5D) as of now; whereas Top Users list has me at 170A+74Q=144 posts.

170 answers + 74 question isn't 144 posts, it's 244 (far closer to what you expected).

And in fact, it [currently reports](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/harry-potter/topusers):

- 173 answers
  [image: Top Harry Potter Answerers]
- 78 questions
  [image: Top Harry Potter Askers]

Which corresponds exactly to what you currently have:

- [173 answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A976+%5Bharry-potter%5D+is%3Aanswer&submit=search)
  [image: DVK's answers in Harry Potter]
- [78 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A976+%5Bharry-potter%5D+is%3Aquestion&submit=search)
  [image: DVK's questions in Harry Potter]

Comment: Do you have the caching rules by any chance?

Comment: @DVK The same as every other cached page? You missed the entire point of my post, which was that you added wrong: this is a non-issue. You had 251 posts in [tag:harry-potter], which is what Top Users reports.

Comment: Please don't concentrate on the obvious **typo**. 244!=250, that was the point of my question. The issue is obviously caching.

Comment: As a more recent example, right now the search shows me with 182 answers in harry-potter, and the users page with the same 173 as your answer